# Generate all possible combinations of an array of size n having exactly k subarrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, combinatorics

It's a combinatorics problem. We can partition the array at max n-1 times and out of it, we have to choose k-1 partitions.

Ex: arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
k = 3, n = 6.

Total possibilities =  `(n-1)C(k-1)` 5C2 = 10.

### Expected Output : (3-dimensional array)

```
[
[[1], [2], [3, 4, 5, 6]], 
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], 
[[1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6]], 
[[1], [2, 3, 4, 5], [6]],
[[1, 2], [3], [4, 5, 6]], 
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], 
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]], 
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]],
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6]],
]
```

Constraints:

1. Subarrays should have at least 1 element.
2. SubArrays should only consist of consecutive elements.
   For ex: [[1, 3], [2, 4], [5, 6]] This is not valid.

So far, I have tried a recursive method but it yields wrong results. I can't wrap my head around how to correct it. I need an answer explaining how to approach this problem properly and the intuition behind it first and then correct my code and point out where I went wrong.

My code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 6;
        int k = 3;
        int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6};
        ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> eachComb = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<Integer> eachSubArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int index = 0;
        
        generateCombinations(arr, k, index, eachSubArray, eachComb, result);
        
        for (ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> each : result) {
            for(ArrayList<Integer> eachh: each) {
                System.out.println(eachh);
            }
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        }
    }

    private static void generateCombinations(int[] arr, int k, int index, ArrayList<Integer> eachSubArray,
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> eachComb, ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> result) {
        

        if(k==0 || index==arr.length) {
            return;
        }
        

        if(!eachSubArray.isEmpty()) {
            eachComb.add(new ArrayList<>(eachSubArray));
        }
        
        if(k==1) {
            ArrayList<Integer> last = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i=index; i<arr.length; i++) {
                last.add(arr[i]);
            }
            if(!last.isEmpty()) {
                eachComb.add((last));
                result.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(eachComb));
                eachComb.remove(eachComb.size()-1);
            }
            return;
        }
        
        eachSubArray.clear();
        
        
        
        for(int i=index; i<arr.length; i++) {
            eachSubArray.add((arr[i]));
            generateCombinations(arr, k-1, i+1, eachSubArray, eachComb, result);
            if(!eachComb.isEmpty()) {
                eachComb.remove(eachComb.size()-1);
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to mention the constraint of having only disjoint subsets made of consecutive elements from the input set. Or, you are missing partitions like `[[1, 3], [2, 4], [5, 6]]`.

Comment: Yea, I mentioned subArrays, not subsets. I thought it would be obvious, but I'll update the question just to be clear, thanks